# Is my milk spoiled?

Tags: milk

How long does it take milk to spoil? I left a gallon of milk in the trunk of my car for about 15 hours. I forgot about it when I got home from shopping, I didn't remember until I woke up the next morning. It is October so the weather is not warm,I would say it was under 60 degrees all night. Is this milk still good? Or should I throw it out?

Comment: It is certainly not safe, having been left at unsafe temperatures (above 40 F) for more than a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Milk spoils pretty quickly (sitting out for the usually considered "safe" time of 2 hours is not recommended with milk, due to it's considerable natural bacterial load), and ~45 degrees is really the maximum storage temperature you should consider (even then, the taste will go off. [40 is the recommended temp](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/food/food_safety/handling/hgic3510.html)).

Comment: We created the model question above as a canonical answer to all of these "I left it out" questions...